# Shortcode conversion to hrml when post is published

Tags: shortcode

I am creating posts in wordpress using shortcode. When user looks at post, the data is displayed by pulling from database.
But we also send email to users when post is published. In this post, we sent the link and the content. But in this case the shortcode function is sent and not the data.

I am writing about the snow storm which is going hit the East Coast.

[myshorcode param1="aa" param2 = "bb"]

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: It is totally impossible to answer this question without seeing your code. File an [edit] with the relevant code

Comment: What is inside shortcode does not matter. How I am using shortcode , I gave an example above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pre_post_update` filter hook to achieve this.

Unfortunately the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_post_update) isn't very good for this hook, but it's a simple enough one to understand and can be found in `wp-includes/post.php` on line 3335 (WP 4.1).

```
add_filter( 'pre_post_update', 'my_replace_shortcode', 2, 99 );
function my_replace_shortcode( $post_id, $data ){

    if(strpos($data['post_content'], '[myshorcode param1="') !== false) :
        $data['post_content'] = do_shortcode('[myshorcode param1="aa" param2 = "bb"]');
    endif;

    return $data;

}
```

What's happening here is a check to see if the `post_content` part of the post contains `[myshorcode param1="` (only check up to here as the value of `param1` will change), and if it does, the whole of `post_content` is replaced with the results of your shortcode.

The `pre_post_update` filter hook is fired right before the post is inserted/updated in the database, and it is fired regardless of whether the post is being inserted or updated.  You can check if it's a new post and only run on that condition if necessary though.

You can also check for a post type if required, or any number of conditions seeing as you basically have the Post that is about to be inserted.

Comment: That looks like it might work. Will try it out. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully it servees your needs, but do let me know if it's not quite there.